# Bootstrap Center Left Right Div breaks on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 for my mobile project . I am designing an header . Like

```
Block1                        Block2                          Block3
```

I want block 1 to be left aligned always on all screen size . Similarly the position of block2 and block3 needs to be in same position .

I don't want to collapse my header.

An Header bar like http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_header

in Bootstrap3

**Update**

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <input type="checkbox" name= "my-checkbox" style="width:100%" checked>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4">
                        <h4 class="ag-top-bar-text rm-dots" style="padding:7px">Header Text</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-4 pull-right">
                        <input type="checkbox" name= "my-checkbox" style="width:100%" checked>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

**HTML**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="pull-left"><a href="#">Block 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Block 2</a></li>
            <li class="pull-right"><a href="#">Block 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Add some **CSS**

```
.navbar-nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/baf9nt7b/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a 12 grid column you should be able to do something like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Block 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Block 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        Block 3
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: I have formated my code can you update and and give me

Comment: Yes your updated code looks ok. How does it look when you preview? Do you have an example/link?